# a controller with multiple repositories in ASP.Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a controller which controls a view which is a criteria search page. The view has a search criteria section at the top and a grid section at the bottom which will display the results from the search.
I have two repositories in my controller, one for Common stuff like combobox values which is associated with Criteria section. The other repository is for the grid data.
I create a viewmodel with both repositories and pass it to my view (as my model) which makes my Model really huge. Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use  [Unit of Work and Repository](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/06/21/revisiting-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework.aspx)